# Snake in Haskell

Tags: beginner, game, haskell, snake-game

I wrote a partial implementation of Snake in Haskell. As of now, it only supports the movement of the snake. However, since the code is getting complex, I'm requesting for a review of the code before I add on the food, growing and scoring functions.

I'd be glad to hear any suggestions on how this code could be written in a more idiomatic and simpler way (namely, `stepSnake` and `step` are long and messy).

```
-- Snake implementation in Haskell.

module Snake (
    newGame
) where

import Control.Lens (set, ix)
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import qualified Data.Sequence as S

-- Size of the grid
n :: Int
n = 5

data Marking = Empty | Food | Snake
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
type Grid = [[Marking]]

emptyGrid :: Int -> Grid
emptyGrid n = replicate n $ replicate n Empty

type Coord = (Int, Int)
data Direction = N | E | W | S
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

stepCoord :: Coord -> Direction -> Coord
stepCoord (i, j) dir = case dir of
    N -> (i - 1, j)
    E -> (i, j + 1)
    W -> (i, j - 1)
    S -> (i + 1, j)

setCoord :: Marking -> Coord -> Grid -> Grid
setCoord mark (i, j) grid = set (ix i . ix j) mark grid

validCoord :: Coord -> Bool
validCoord (i, j) = i > 0 && j > 0 && i < n && j < n

type Snake = S.Seq Coord

newSnake :: Int -> Snake
newSnake n = S.fromList [c, c', c'']
    where c = (n `div` 2, n `div` 2)
          c' = stepCoord c E
          c'' = stepCoord c' E

stepSnake :: Snake -> Direction -> Maybe (Coord, Snake, Coord)
stepSnake snake dir = if validCoord tail' && not (tail' `elem` toList snake')
                      then Just (head, snake'', tail')
                      else Nothing
    where (head, snake') = case S.viewl snake of
              S.EmptyL -> error "snake is empty"
              x S.:< xs -> (x, xs)
          tail = case S.viewr snake of
              S.EmptyR -> error "snake is empty"
              _ S.:> x -> x
          tail' = stepCoord tail dir
          snake'' = snake' S.|> tail'

data Game = Game {
    grid :: Grid,
    snake :: Snake
} deriving Show

newGame :: Game 
newGame = Game {
    grid = foldl (flip $ setCoord Snake) (emptyGrid n) (toList snake),
    snake = snake
} where snake = newSnake n

step :: Game -> Direction -> Maybe Game
step (Game grid snake) dir = case stepSnake snake dir of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just (head, snake', tail') -> Just $ Game (foldl f grid [(head, Empty), (tail', Snake)]) snake'
    where f grid (coord, mark) = setCoord mark coord grid
```

Comment: How do I actually make use of this code?

Comment: What do you plan to use it for?

Comment: As a reference for my own exercise of implementing it. Why?

Comment: I think you can start from `newGame` and see how the grid changes as you run `step game dir`, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Ok, undestood, thanks. I gave for granted you were presenting a _playable_ game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little dangerous to define a top-level constant like `n`, the name isn't descriptive or distinctive and you end up shadowing it quite a bit. A compiling but incorrect typo is almost inevitable. Since you gave it a definitive comment, why not just give it that name instead? Try `defaultGridSize`.

I can see why you may have used a `case` statement in `stepCoord` (to save typing out `stepCoord (i, j)` repeatedly), but I have a strong preference in the other direction. All pattern-matching which can happen at the top-level generally should.

```
stepCoord :: Coord -> Direction -> Coord
stepCoord (i, j) N = (i - 1, j)
-- etc...
```

Or you can write a handy little utility function and reorder your arguments to write a point-free function.

```
tuply :: (a -> c, b -> d) -> (a, b) -> (c, d) -- tuple, apply, two ply!
tuply (f, g) (a, b) = (f a, g b)

stepCoord :: Direction -> Coord -> Coord
stepCoord N = tuply (subtract 1, id        )
stepCoord E = tuply (id        , + 1       )
stepCoord W = tuply (id        , subtract 1)
stepCoord S = tuply (+ 1       , id        )
```

Generally all your types should be at the top of the file, i.e. `Snake` and `Game`.

I might use a list comprehension in writing `newSnake` to clean it up a little and reduce potential errors from referencing the wrong `c('('))` value.

```
newSnake :: Int -> Snake
newSnake boardSize = S.fromList [(mid, j) | j <- [mid .. mid + 2]]
  where mid = boardSize `div` 2
```

Right-hand sides composed solely of an if-statement are good candidates for writing guards.

```
stepSnake snake dir
    | validCoord tail' && not (tail' `elem` toList snake') = Just (head, snake'', tail')
    | otherwise                                            = Nothing
```

This is a very dense function though, I think it might be easier to write if you wrap the version using a `Seq` snake around a primitive list version. Your snakes will presumably never grow so long as to actually cause a user noticeable slowdown between steps due to list processing, so you might think about tossing out `Seq` altogether.

```
stepSnake :: Snake -> Direction -> Maybe (Coord, Snake, Coord)
stepSnake snake dir = fmap (second fromList) (stepSnakeList (toList snake) dir)
  where second f (a, b, c) = (a, f b, c)

stepSnakeList :: [Coord] -> Direction -> Maybe (Coord, [Coord], Coord)
stepSnakeList snake dir
    | validCoord newHead && not (newHead `elem` snake) = Just (oldTail, newSnake, newHead)
    | otherwise                                        = Nothing
  where
    oldTail  = head snake
    body     = tail snake
    oldHead  = last snake
    newHead  = stepCoord oldHead dir
    newSnake = body ++ [newHead]
```

Use `foldl'` from `Data.List` instead of `foldl` for `newGame` and `step`. [Why?](http://www.well-typed.com/blog/90/) It's a long story.

Comment: `(Control.Arrow.&&&)` can do the job `tuply` is.

Comment: Sure, but then you've got to be willing to use `Control.Arrow`.

Comment: @bisserlis Thanks for your feedback! I'll follow your suggestions and post a new version for review. @Carl Would you mind giving an example? I'm not familiar with `Control.Arrow`.

Comment: @wei2912 `stepCoord N = subtract 1 &&& id` would be the first branch if you have `Control.Arrow` imported.

Comment: @Carl Alright, giving that a try.

Comment: @Carl That doesn't seem to typecheck. Expected type: Coord -> Int for both `subtract 1` and `id`.

Comment: Whoops.  I got my operators mixed up.  You'd actually want `***` instead of `&&&`. `stepCoord N = subtract 1 *** id`